# Can $[x, x+2\pi]$ cover the real line?

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous, but we are not allowed to use the MVT or unit circle.

I proved that $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, 2\pi]$, and we know that $\sin x$ is periodical with period $2\pi$, so $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $[2n\pi, (2n+2)\pi]$

However, I don't know if I can conclude that $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ from this, since I'm not sure if $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered by the set of closed intervals (or any set of closed intervals, for that matter).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why aren't you sure?  Let $y$ be a real number.  Is there some interval of the form $[2n\pi, (2n+2)\pi]$ containing $y$?

Comment: Uh...I didn't realize this, I was trying to prove that using some much more complicated stuff, and got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R} \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \big[2n\pi, (2n + 2)\pi\big].
\end{equation}

Given some $p \in \mathbb{R}$, can you find an $n$ such that $p \in \big[2n\pi, (2n + 2)\pi\big]$? If so, you've shown that intervals of the desired form do in fact cover $\mathbb{R}$.